# Security error when attempting to manipulate image data of SVG in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/5emz372r/

I am programmatically generating an SVG data URI, then rendering it in the canvas. Any attempts to use getImageData from that point on throw this error:

```
SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

Does drawing an SVG to canvas automatically taint the canvas?

Side note: My ultimate goal here is to render a custom webfont (loaded by data URI) onto the canvas; is there an alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is broken, keeps crashing when I go to it.

The likely cause of this issue is you are trying to access a photo, or file, that is located on another domain.  Browser security wont let you do this in most cases.

[SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 when applying document.domain on both sites. How do I resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034431/security-err-dom-exception-18-when-applying-document-domain-on-both-sites-how)

Comment: It's not broken for me, try another browser. I'm attempting to access a data URI. Not something located on a different domain.

Comment: where is the image coming from that you are attempting to access a data uri for

Comment: I'm generating it myself within the JS. (I'm taking a mostly pre-made SVG format string, adding in the variables that need to change, and then btoa()ing it and putting it into a data URI.)

Comment: Something is making the browser thing you are breaking CORS, from your description I am not sure what that is.  Sorry